# SessionAttributes and redirect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a SessionAttributes key on a Controller that I set in a method

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/")
@SessionAttributes("approve")
public class MyController{
  @RequestMapping
  public String do(
        @ModelAttribute("vo") CommandVO vo,
        @RequestParam("approve") boolean approve,
        BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        NativeWebRequest request
  )
  model.setAttribute("approve",approve);
  [...]
  return "redirect:/bla";
}
```

The variable doesn't end up in the session.

Is it possible that the redirect creates a problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On redirects you should use the `RedirectAttributes` variable in your method signature instead of using model:

```
  redirectAttributes.addAttribute("approve", approve);
```

This works the same way as the `model`, but it is an specialization for this occasions that you need to do a `redirect:/`

[Documentation about RedirectAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to put your param in RedirectAttributes, instead of Model. If you would like to access your parameter from another controller, you can use `addFlashAttribute()` (see [FlashMap](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FlashMap.html)) method, otherwise normal `addAttribute()` will also work.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/")
@SessionAttributes("approve")
public class MyController{
  @RequestMapping
  public String do(
        @ModelAttribute("vo") CommandVO vo,
        @RequestParam("approve") boolean approve,
        BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        NativeWebRequest request
  )
  redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("approve",approve);
  // or redirectAttributes.addAttribute("approve",approve);

  return "redirect:/bla";
}
```

From [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

> A specialization of the Model interface that controllers can use to
>   select attributes for a redirect scenario